# ruby creating hash for array.each

Tags: ruby, hash

This is my code:

```
@games.each do |game| #@games is an array
  #definitely working 
  game = Hash.new 0
end
```

And as you can guess... it's not working. No errors. Just variables like that don't exist. I want my hashes be called by a title of games. Plenty of this, because there are 240titles.

I am pretty sure I have to take this "game = Hash.new 0" out of block, but to be honest I don't have any ideas.

Regards.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a sample input array with a few elements, and the desired result.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what you're asking for but let me try and sorry for my stupidity. After one method I stay with array which looks like this: ["steam", "age_of_Empires_II:_HD_Edition", "anomaly_Warzone_Earth", "bEEP", "bEEP", "bEEP", "blockstorm", "brütal_Legend"] and so on (as I said there is 240titles). As I said I want my hashes to be called from name from this array. For example one hash would be "bEEP", second would be "blockstorm" and so on.

Comment: @Frederick Cheung I dont know if I am doing something pointless but I wanted to create a new hashes from elements from an array. Each array element would be a variable with Hash class.

Comment: It sounds like you want to create 240 local variable each named from the array element. But you really don't want that. @maximf's answer is close to what you want.

Comment: Just as I thought - it was a stupid solution. Seems I gotta find something better. Thanks for all those support and yeah, that what I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend reading "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We can't help you if you don't tell us more about the problem, using code and data to demonstrate it. Explanations around the code are necessary too, but code tells us a lot more than commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `game` contains each element of the array, passed one-by-one by `each`, so you should try this:

```
games_hash = {}

@games.each do |game|
  games_hash[game] = 0
end
```

Comment: I can see what it is doing but thats not what I wanted. I wanted to create new Hash for every game so I can put more information(keys) about it eg. "coins", "accounts", "how_many_friends_i_have_there". It would be a mess if I added 240games to one hash and tried to add 5more informations for each game.

Comment: Use a hash of hashes is typically how you would achieve this. For a better answer, I suggest you provide some more code (even if it's not 'real' code, just something we can get a feel for) that shows how you want to use the data structure you are creating.

Comment: I was thinking multi-level hashes and thought it's a bad idea... now I am doing this with your post as 'guide' and it's really easy. Now I can't even understand why I wanted to make all those variables with multi-level hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use each_with_object.

```
games_hash = @games.each_with_object({}) do |game, hash|
  hash[game] = 0
end
```

You can also initialize the hash with 0.

```
games_hash = @games.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |game, hash|
  hash[game]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of references:

Inside the `each` block the `game` variable is a reference to a game but it's not the game itself.

When you assign a new instance to `game` i.e.: ('game = Hash.new'), you are changing the value of that reference. Now `game` is not pointing to one of the games in the array, but now it's pointing to a new Hash.

I'm not sure if this is what you want, by try this:

```
games_hash = {}
@games.each do |game|
  games_hash[game] = {}
end
```